# How to update user input of a form when i am using header that links to other file?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, variables

I am writing a form using php and mysql. The main goal is to make the form 
(1) detect missing field.
(2) update user input after successful submit and
(3) most importantly to avoid re-submission on reload/refresh.
 I am able to manage the first and the third one but doesn't have any idea on the second one. 
Here's my code (able to achieve first and third)

form1.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $name = "";
        $class = "";
        $school = "";

        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $class = $_POST["class"];
            $school = $_POST["school"];
            $output = false;

            if(empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["class"]) || empty($_POST["school"])){
                    echo 'field cannot be empty';
                    $output_form = true;
            }
            if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["class"]) && !empty($_POST["school"])){
                    $hostname = "localhost";
                    $admin = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $database = "testdatabase";

                    $dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $admin, $password, $database) or die("database connection error");

                    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `sorty` (`name`, `class`, `school`) VALUES ('$name', '$class', '$school')";
                    $insert_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $insert_query) or die("error");
                    if($insert_result == 1)
                        echo "data inserted";
                    else
                        echo "insert query failed";

                    mysqli_close($dbc);
                    header('Location: form2.php');
            }
        }
        else
            $output = true;

        if($output){
        ?>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>"/><br/>
                Class: <input type="text" name="class" value="<?php echo $class?>"/><br/>
                School: <input type="text" name="school" value="<?php echo $school?>"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
            </form>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My second file form2.php(succesful page after form submission)

```
<body>
Name: /*user input here*/<br/>
Class: /*user input here*/<br/>
School: /*user input here*/<br/>
```

As I can't access the variable $name, $class, $school of form.php I am having problem updating the user input data. So is there anyway to access the variable across file or is it not possible to do in this way.

Answer (score 0):

[user_name](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9dZrzyA-1rCUUt2ZlpZVUhIV1U) you may check this out. and read the code. i hope you will get the answer. You may add session for showing the message that the specified operation is done. thank you :)

Comment: Welcome.As you know if you get your answer you should make the answer excepted and vote the question if you satisfy with the answer.Because i spend times for your question.and wrote code for you.
;)

Comment: I try to upvote but my reputation is below 15 so it's not taking any effect. I will do it when I reach 15 rep.